# Modifying depth-first search

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

(source, destination) and it's type (tree, back, forward, cross)?

Comment: have you tried doing yourself ,first of all try and put your code if you have tried

Comment: By remembering where you came from. Please add some code for a Depth First Search to your question and we'll take it from there.

Comment: Your edited question is even less understandable than the original. Please explain, *in words*, what you're trying to do. And if you're asking how to modify some code, be sure to show the code you're trying to modify.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. Code in Java

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Node {
    public String name;
    public List<Node> connections = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean visited = false;

    Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class DFS {
    // Main part.
    public static void search(Node root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
        root.visited = true;
        for (Node node : root.connections) {
            if (!node.visited) {
                // Print result.
                System.out.println(root.name + "->" + node.name);
                search(node);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node a = new Node("a");
        Node b = new Node("b");
        Node c = new Node("c");
        Node d = new Node("d");
        Node e = new Node("e");

        a.connections.add(b);

        b.connections.add(a);
        b.connections.add(c);
        b.connections.add(d);

        c.connections.add(b);
        c.connections.add(d);

        d.connections.add(b);
        d.connections.add(c);
        d.connections.add(e);

        DFS.search(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.

This is the solution based on [the source you posted as comment](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/DepthFirstSearch.html).
IMPORTANT: There is an error on the start/end table, third row third column should be "end[u] < end[v]" instead of "end[u] > end[v]"

```
    void main(G, s){
        for each node v in G{
            explored[v]=false
            parent[v]=null
            start[v]=end[v]=null
        }
        Global clock = 0
        DFS(G, s, s)
    }

    void DFS(G, s, parent){
        explored[s] = true;
        parent[s] = parent

        start[s]=clock
        clock++

        for each u=(s,v){
            if(explored[v] == false){
                 DFS(G, v)
            } 
            print (s + "-->" + v +"type: " + getType(s,v))
        }

        end[s]=clock
        clock++
    }

    String getType(s, v){
        if(start[s]<start[v]){
            if(end[s]>end[v]) return "Tree edge"
            else return "Forward edge"
        else{
            if(end[s]<end[v]) return "Back edge"
            else return "Cross edge"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks correct. However, an important part is to be able to implement `isOneOfParents` (ancestors I presume) in O(1). [It is possible](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/DepthFirstSearch.html) if we store the entry and exit times in each vertex.

Comment: The first implementation that i thought for isOneOfParents (yes, ancestors), was O(max depth of the tree). Using your source i'll try to make it O(1)

Comment: Ok. Thanks to [your source](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/DepthFirstSearch.html) i undestood the timer use. I'm editing the answer to add it.